# Representing a C# accessor property in a UML Class Diagram?

Tags: c#, properties, uml, accessor

How does one represent a C# property (setter and getter accessors) in a UML Class diagram?

Do you just write it as regular setter and getter methods?

Or is there some other way of representing it?

I'm interested in how accessors are represented in a class and interface in a UML Class diagram.

Comment: It's starting to seem like this isn't a good answer to this question, like it's too objective or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some developers / analysts:

(1) show properties as a very conceptual thing, and only show a single row per property.

(2) Others, are more specific, and display 3 rows, the property, the "getter" function, the "setter" function.

(3) And sometimes, only show 2, for the accesors.

(4) Some U.M.L. drawing apps. allows you to select which of the prior, do you want to display.

And...

...As far as I have investigated, all options are right. Remember, that stereotypes ("<<some stuff>>", are allowed to help document the class.

(Note: I replace spaces by dots)

(1) Only plain property (C#, very conceptual):

```
+================================================================+
|..........................MyClass...............................|
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|..[+]..|..void....|..MyClass()...|..<<constructor>>.............|
|..[+]..|..void....|..~MyClass()..|..<<destructor>>..............|
+================================================================+
|..[+]..|..string..|..Text........|..<<property>>................|
+================================================================+
```

(2) Only "accesors", (C++, Java, style):

```
+================================================================+
|..........................MyClass...............................|
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|..[+]..|..void....|..MyClass()...|..<<constructor>>.............|
|..[+]..|..void....|..~MyClass()..|..<<destructor>>..............|
+================================================================+
|..[#]..|..string..|..FText.......|..<<field>>...................|
+================================================================+
|..[+]..|..string..|..getText()...|..<<function>>,..<<getter>>...|
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|..[+]..|..string..|..setText()...|..<<procedure>>,..<<setter>>..|
+================================================================+
```

(2) Everything (Very Programmer, Object Pascal / Delphi style):

```
+================================================================+
|..........................MyClass...............................|
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|..[+]..|..void....|..MyClass()...|..<<constructor>>.............|
|..[+]..|..void....|..~MyClass()..|..<<destructor>>..............|
+================================================================+
|..[#]..|..string..|..FText.......|..<<field>>...................|
+================================================================+
|..[+]..|..string..|..Text........|..<<property>>................|
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|..[+]..|..string..|..getText()...|..<<function>>,..<<getter>>...|
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|..[+]..|..string..|..setText()...|..<<procedure>>,..<<setter>>..|
+================================================================+
```

Are you delivering to analysts ?
Does your C++ / Java programmers know that if the diagram shows only properties, they have to code the acccesors, or your company requires to explicity declared them in the diagrams ?

Choose the one that fits more your needs. (remove dots).

Comment: Good answer.  I guess it depends on who's going to read the documentation and what they're expecting.  If you don't know what they're expecting I guess I would have to go with (2) there, although it does seem a bit verbose.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you really need to worry about how to represent language-specific conventions in a UML diagram. After all, that is an implementation concern, not a design concern. I'd recommend representing your accessor methods as you would in any other UML diagram and then work out the implementation of your design when you get to that point in the project and not one minute sooner.

Sorry, I realize this is not really a direct answer to your question, but it is good practice nonetheless.

Comment: @Martinho: In theory, your what-if has no bearing on my answer. One would still write getXXX and setXXX methods into the UML. In practice, however, I suspect that many system architects would create public properties to represent them.

Comment: Don't the accessors just get converted into something like:
public string get_MyProp() { return foo; }
public void set_myProp(string value) { foo = value; }?

Comment: @MattC In which language. In .NET (C#, VB) version 3.0, the compiler allows you to generate the accesors automatically, in case no aditional operations are required, very helpful.

Comment: Martinho is right. U.M.L. can be used to describe operations that do not become a software application.

Answer (score 0):

It should be set as an attribute. If it only has a getter, set it to readonly. There is no specific UML for C# properties.

Comment: Right. There no specific U.M.L. for any language. It up to each Soft. Dev. dept. how to implement a conceptual U.M.L. class diagram into a particular progr. lang. Im not a fan of "read only" properties as C# allows, I rather use a protected field, a public readAttribute function, and modify the field in other part of code.