# How to translate this C# class into UML

Tags: c#, uml

How can I create a UML Class Diagram for the given C# Code

```
// A class for two-dimensional objects.
class TwoDShape {
    double pri_width;
    double pri_height;
    // Properties for Width and Height.
    public double Width {
        get { return pri_width; }
        set { pri_width = value < 0 ? -value : value; }
    }
    public double Height {
        get { return pri_height; }
        set { pri_height = value < 0 ? -value : value; }
    }
    public void ShowDim() {
        Console.WriteLine("Width and height are " +
        Width + " and " + Height);
    }
}
```

How do represent the above class properties Width and Height in the class diagram ? UML Specification doesn't tell anything about this kind of class representation in the C# code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Representing a C# accessor property in a UML Class Diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432591/representing-a-c-sharp-accessor-property-in-a-uml-class-diagram)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how [Sparx Enterprise Architect](https://sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html) answers your question using "*Code Engineering -> Import from source file(s)*"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

UML **is and must** be language agnostique. 
So the more logical answer, for me, would be that Width and Height are UML properties.

Then Modelling tools must add stereotypes or annotation to differenciate Width and pri_width UML properties.

Below another screenshot coming from [Modelio Tool](https://www.modelio.org)

[image]